# Prove that the limit of a convergent subsequence of a bounded sequence is in closed interval

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Say $x_n$ is a bounded sequence in a closed interval [a, b] and $y_n$ is the convergent subsequence. how can I prove that the limit of the convergent subsequence must be in the interval [a, b]?

Since $x_n$ is bounded within the interval [a, b]. Thus, for every subsequence $y_n$ of $x_n$, $y_n$ must be in the closed interval as well. Thus, the limit of convergent subsequence must be in the interval. Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. You only need the fact that $[a,b]$ is a closed set in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: However you do need the "Heine-Borel property," that closed and bounded implies compact, to conclude that $x_n$ has a convergent subsequence in the first place. Also, $x_n$ being a sequence in a bounded set automatically makes it bounded - this should be obvious from the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow you need to use the closeness of $[a,b]$

You may approach by contradiction. If the limit of the convergent subsequence is not in $[a, b]$, then either the limit is larger than $b$ or less than $a$

Now both cases leads to contradiction because you may choose a small neighborhood of the limit which does not intersect $[a,b]$ contrary to the terms being in $[a,b]$